# How to catch unhandled exceptions when using .NET Remoting

Tags: c#, error-handling, remoting

I want to catch all unhandled exceptions thrown in a remote object on *the server* and log them there before I translate them into some custom exception so that specific exceptions do not cross the client/server boundary.

I think I have to use a custom channel sync, but can anyone confirm this and/or have any other advice to give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding [Eliyahu Baker's](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/bikta/articles/17324.aspx) helpful blog post and reading chapter 12 of [Rammer's Advanced .NET Remoting](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590594177) I wrote a custom channel sink that does what I want. This intercepts any exception and logs it locally before sending it on to the client.

Ideally, I'd like to log the exception and raise a more generic one for the client, but I haven't cracked that nut yet.

Comment: Are you willing to share more details?  I tried using Eliyahu Baker's technique (after finding the blog post on archive.org) but it doesn't seem to catch the remoting-exception that happens on the server when the client unexpectedly disconnects (which is what I'm trying to deal with, mostly).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Microsoft Enterprise Library Exception Handling app block -- it lets you handle errors and convert specific types of exception to a different type of exception before rethrowing to the client.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of this. I don't think it addresses my issue though as I want to catch *unhandled exceptions*. It seems to me that the EHAB is about applying a policy for coded exception handlers. I just want to log the unexpected exceptions so we can code the appropriate handlers in later code versions.